# Problems with vlookup function in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoDZR.jpg)[vlookup]

Erradic/inconsistent behavior with vlookup function in MS Excel.

The search list is in yellow, search result is in green.

Please refer to the captured image.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with vlookup.

Vlookup will look in the first column for what you want, in this case it looks in column A for “round” and returns n/a which is perfectly correct.

You could 4 vlookups to deal with this or you can try index and match ...

Comment: Thanks. Since column A contains "round", I would think the result would be "window" not #N/A.

Comment: Cells A1 to A5 do NOT contain “round” cell A13 does, BUT that is the lookup value...

Comment: You have specified the range as A1 to E5, so vlookup wiill index cells A1 to A5 ...

Comment: I understand: The manual states, "The value to look for in the first column of a table." Thank you again!